# DOM manipulation through VanillaJS in VueJS Framework

Tags: vue.js

I've started using VueJS a month ago. I've watched many tutorials to learn the language, but generally I never see developers using the DOM methods such as getElementById or getElementByClassName to make manipulations onto an element that is inside of a component or inside a view.
I'd like to give an example to make my statement more clear.
For example lets suppose that we have a nested component called UsernameInput that is an input[type="text"].
Instead of having to pass the value through the @input directive, we could get the value from the parent using the document.getElementById(/* Id Of The Input /*).value . I know that Vue uses the Virtual DOM for the rendering to make it faster. But does using VanillaJS affect it in any sort of way? And why is it so rarely used in front-end frameworks

Comment: maybe reading [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Vue_refs_focus_management#virtual_dom_and_refs) could help you to understand the reason.

Comment: It’s kind of the entire point of Vue that the UI *follows* the code and is bound and updated implicitly, without you needing to interact with DOM nodes explicitly.

Comment: By sticking to raw DOM you both fight the way the framework normally works (it won't catch the modifications made directly, and vice versa) and discard the developments it brings - both technical (performance, avoiding leaks) and architectural (good code on the big scale). This is the reason this is not done, to not spoil the whole barrel with a bad apple.